# Handle routes when using Angular combined with Express (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I have the following config in angular

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../pages/main.html',
            controller: 'RMController',
            controllerAs: 'rm'
        })

        .when('/:user', {
            templateUrl: '../pages/emp-details.html'
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```

This works fine if click on something in `main.html`, which then takes me to the `emp-details.html`.

But, if I explicitly type `localhost:8080/1234` (`emp-details.html` with param), express has never heard of that route.

What is the best way to handle this kind of relationship?

My routes looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(app, schema) {

    //Finds all users
    app.get('/api/users', function(req, res){
        schema.getEmployees()

            .then(function(results) {
                res.json(results);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) res.json(err);
            });
    });

    app.get('/api/users/:user', function(req, res) {
         schema.getSpecificEmployee(req.params.user)

            .then(function(results) {
                res.json(results);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) res.json(err);
            });
    });

    //Our default path: index.html
    app.get('*', function(req, res){
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this happening locally or on your web server?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
    .when('/:user', {
        url: '/emp-detail',    //add this line
        templateUrl: '../pages/emp-details.html'
    })
```

Now if you do `localhost:8080/#/emp-detail`, you should see the emp-details.html page.
By using localhost:8080/#/xyz u should be able to access your routes.
Hope this works!!!

Comment: Nilzone is using the html5 mode, so I presume he wants his links to look like `localhost:8080/userId`. Also this would defeat sharing the url for a particular user, as it's never shown.